# Add see more option to the server data in angular 8

Tags: angular, angular8

I am facing an issue with my project.

I want to add `see more` option to a paragraph and that paragraph's data is coming from a server.

I know how to add `see more` option to HTML paragraph, but I don't know how to add `see more` option to the data that is coming from the server.

```
<p>Jayesh Vyas Jayesh Vyas Jayesh Vyas Jayesh Vyas Jayesh Vyas 
Jayesh Vyas Jayesh Vyas Jayesh Vyas Jayesh Vyas Jayesh Vyas 
Jayesh Vyas Jayesh Vyas <span id="dots">...</span>
<span id="more">Jayesh Vyas Jayesh Vyas Jayesh Vyas Jayesh Vyas 
Jayesh Vyas Jayesh Vyas Jayesh Vyas Jayesh Vyas Jayesh Vyas 
Jayesh Vyas Jayesh Vyas Jayesh Vyas Jayesh Vyas Jayesh Vyas 
Jayesh Vyas Jayesh Vyas Jayesh Vyas Jayesh Vyas Jayesh Vyas 
Jayesh Vyas Jayesh Vyas Jayesh Vyas .</span></p>
<button onclick="myFunction()" id="myBtn">Read more</button>
```

**JavaScript code**

```
<script>
function myFunction() {
  var dots = document.getElementById("dots");
  var moreText = document.getElementById("more");
  var btnText = document.getElementById("myBtn");

  if (dots.style.display === "none") {
    dots.style.display = "inline";
    btnText.innerHTML = "Read more"; 
    moreText.style.display = "none";
  } else {
    dots.style.display = "none";
    btnText.innerHTML = "Read less"; 
    moreText.style.display = "inline";
  }
}
</script>
```

So you can see above I tried above code for a paragraph and it is working fine for me.

**but in my project, the HTML component is as below.**

```
<div  class="col-12 col-lg-12" *ngFor="let post of rec?.attributes?.Postings | filter : searchText | filter:filterText; let i=index">
<div class="col-12 noRightPadding" style="overflow-wrap: break-word;white-space: pre-line;word-break:break-all;
">{{post?.attributes?.Message}} </div>
</div>
```

you can see the paragraph is coming as `post.attributes.Message` and I don't have an idea how to add `see more` option for this if it exceeds more than two lines.

can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-szlzyv) You can do it with if condition and create one more property for each element such as post?.attributes?.isMore as default false

```
   <div  class="col-12 col-lg-12" >
        <div class="col-12 noRightPadding">
           {{ post?.attributes?.Message.length>100 ? post?.attributes?.Message.substring(0,10)+'...': post?.attributes?.Message}} 
            <a *ngIf=" post?.attributes?.Message.length>10"(click)="post?.attributes?.isMore=!post?.attributes?.isMore">{{!post?.attributes?.isMore && post?.attributes?.Message.length>10 ? 'Read More' : 'Read Less' }}</a> </div> 
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Hi your solution is good and it works for me but there are multiple paragraphs that are coming from the server and I am displaying by iterating a ng-For loop.

Now when I click on the first paragraph's read more, it is opening the other paragraphs also.

can you tell me how to deal with it by giving a unique id or something?

Comment: You need to put one more attribute in your each model element. post?.attributes?.isMore so all element will have own show hide boolean after u get data from server add ishow to each one as default false. I edited demo now you can check it . You can also send this parameter from server

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like:

```
<p class="text-center">{{ post.attributes.Message.length <= 50 ? post.attributes.Message : post.attributes.Message.substring(0, 50) + '...' }}</p>
```

if your text contain more than 50 characters then it will only display 50 characters.

Answer (score 1):

I strongly recommand you to use `word-wrap` and `text-overflow` CSS properties.

Example: https://codepen.io/doliG/pen/oNjrVBK

With angular, the toggle function can simply change a boolean value

```js
class MyComponent {
  showFullText = false;

  toggle() {
    this.showFullText = !this.showFullText;
  }
}
```

And then in template, something like

```html
<p [class.something]="showFullText">{{ veryLongText }}</p>
```

Good luck.